# Google+ SignIn Hybrid Approach IOS/Python REST Server

Tags: ios, google-plus, tornado

We are trying to incorporate the Google+ SignIn button for authentication to our IOS client and python tornado REST Server.

On the IOS client, we followed the "Enable server-side API access for your app" in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in.  We set the  clientID to the Google+ IOS Client and the homeServerClientID to our web server Google+ Web client id.

Then on our tornado werver, we used the python google+ client and did:

```
oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, scope='email')
oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

So the IOS client works fine, it authenticates, gets the one time token in  homeServerAuthorizationCode.  It sends this to the REST API and it produces an exception:

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1964, in step2_exchange
    raise FlowExchangeError(error_msg)
FlowExchangeError: redirect_uri_mismatch

We have tried to use difference codes, double and triple checked the client ids in the clientsecrets, IOS and tornado code and they are all correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that it's not happy with the redirect URI on the server side. `'postmessage'` is absolutely right for the web flow, but for iOS try either not specifying redirect_uri at all, or using `'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'` (oob being "out of browser") for the redirect_uri.

Comment: For an IOS client, it doesn't seem like one can do anything, the dev console hard codes it to
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost

Which seems like it shoudld be set to the above.

Comment: You should be able to use that string on the server side though when you're exchanging - the redirect URI gets passed to the auth server as part of the code exchange request.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding.  The client has the urn...oob string and localhost, the web client has postmessage in the request_uri.  Should I use the urn...oob instead of postmessage on the server?

Comment: That's it precisely - on the web server use either oob or nothing as the redirect_uri. I appreciate this means you need to distinguish between server requests that are sourced from the browser and from iOS/Android.